# How to fix regex function that ignores if statement?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, text

I have the following python dataframe

[image]

## And I've written the following code that I want to:

### the urls

1. for every URL in the Landing_Page column, search for URLs that contain "/2019/" in them and assaign a new variable to them called "new_model_core_incentives"
2. for every URL in the Landing_Page column, search for URLs that contain any year besides 2019, and assign a new variable to them called "used_model_core_incentives"

### the keywords

1. search through every row of the keywords column, and for keywords that contain "2019" in them, create a new variable and call it new_word
2. **search through every row of the keywords column, and for keywords that contain no year what so ever, call those new_word**
3. search through every row of the keywords column, and for keywords that contain years not 2019, call them old_words

```
for Landing_Page in zip(df.Landing_Page):
      # the url
    if "/2019/" in Landing_Page:
        new_model_core_incentives = Landing_Page
        print(f"new_model_core_incentives {new_model_core_incentives}")
    elif re.search("/(?:(?:20)|(?:19))\d{2}/", url):
        used_model_core_incentives = Landing_Page 
        print(f"used_model_core_incentives {used_model_core_incentives}")    

        # the "keywords"
    if "2019" in Keyword:
        new_word = Keyword
        print(f"new_word {new_word}")
    elif re.search("(?:(?:20)|(?:19))\d{2}", Keyword) is None:
        old_word = Keyword
        print(f"old_word {old_word}")
```

## When I run this code I get the following errors:

[image: 1. List item]

**When I try running the blocks separately, I run into the issue of all the urls being classified as "used_model_core_incentives" despite the fact that they contain "/2019/" in them.**

**I also can not get the function to look at the keywords block at all.**

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Please do not post images but copy/paste the text into your question.

Comment: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` - the `Keyword` must to be a type <str> or <bytes>

Comment: Sidenote - What IDE are you using? The error messages pointing you to the line is awseome.

Comment: @FailSafe I'm using jupyter notebook stylized with a notebook thingy I found on github lol

Comment: Sooo, /i was looking at your `Keyword` regex. Why exactly are you using `|(?:19)` at all? That "will" end up capturing 2019...

Comment: @FailSafe in a previous version of the script where i supplied a list instead of a dataframe it worked for me, so i assumed it would still work. How should I edit it?

Comment: In all honesty, I would have gone for something much more simple. Try testing this regex against these:  `>>> keywords_string = '''chevy traverse dealer incentives
2017 kia sorento rebates
2017 kia sorento rebates
2019 nissan promo
dodge ram 1500 deals
2006 ford edge
toyota prius dealer incentives
dodge 2019 expo
vw passat deals
2017 toyota 4runner incentives'''` Then use this regex (I'm using findall because it gives direct output)  `>>> re.findall("20(?!19)\d{2}", keywords_string)`. You'll have to put in the line breaks and use `flags = re.M`

Comment: Following up again from that last post so you can see it `>>> re.findall("20(?!19)\d{2}", keywords_string)`. You'll have to put in the line breaks and use `flags = re.M`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elif re.search("(?:(?:20)|(?:19))\d{2}", Keyword) is None:`

is missing foreslashes it should be:

`elif re.search("/(?:(?:20)|(?:19))\d{2}/", Keyword) is None:`

EDIT:

as @s3n0 mentioned are you shure that `Keyword` is a string? I've tested both cases and it executes in both.

Comment: I get the following error: File "<ipython-input-74-5ac558695a08>", line 5
    elif(re.search("(?:(?:20)|(?:19))\d{2}/",, Keyword), is, None:)
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I made an mistake in the second line the you need a foreslash on the start and the end of your regex string.

Comment: New error: 
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object  (I keep trying to convert the columns to strings but they keep returning as objects ?!?)

Comment: Did you check that your `Keyword` Variable is a string?

Comment: Ive used  df["Keyword"] = df["Keyword"].astype(str) and it keeps coming back as object dtype

Comment: since I don't know what df is exactly I assume that it only can store `dtypes` try inputting `df["Keyword"].astype(str)` into the regex.

Comment: the problem appears to have been in the zip function... edited it as this and it worked! for Keyword, Landing_Page in zip(df["Keyword"], df["Landing_Page"]):